# Objective-C and TBXML: How to accept mime-type "application/xml" with TBXML?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, http, ios4

The [TBXML documentation](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html) is pretty small and the API didn't give me any hints as how I should define how to accept mime-type "application/xml" with TBXML, as I'm requesting data from a webservice that serves HTML as default but can serve XML if requested (and I need the XML).

Is there some way to do this with the API? Or is there a workaround? I didn't try any request processing with iOS SDK so far, so maybe there's an obvious answer I just don't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open TBXML source code, you'll see that initWithURL is defined as ...

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)aURL {
    self = [self initWithXMLString:[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:aURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]];
```

... and there's no way how to say that you want to receive XML.

You should look at NSMutableURLRequest, NSURLConnection and download it by yourself. You can set HTTP header field Accept in NSMutableURLRequest and then you can use this request in NSURLConnection to download it.

Comment: That's what I've been doing now and using the NSData I got back with TBXML. Maybe I could've subclassed TBXML and used my connection code with an additional initializer ... if I happen to do that anytime soon, I'll link to my class :-)